# Character Encoding Issue in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, character-encoding, decoding, turkish

I have a problem with turkish character while reading string from realtime db.

When i read turkish 'ş' character from real-time db, it returns 'ÅŸ'.

Ascii codes of the string 'ÅŸ' is 197,376. How to decode this string into turkish

'ş' character back ?

Comment: How can an ASCII code be over 127 - or even over 256 when considering a codepage like ISO 8859-9? Are you sure it's 197 376? You propably have a problem with your encoding - it looks like your db is saving the values in UTF-8 and you are interpreting them with another encoding.

Comment: Please send your code. How do you open the file? What encoding are you using? What is the encoding of your DB?

Comment: Hi Marwie,sorry for miswriting,197 and 376 are the integer codes of the characters.When i try to decode 'ÅŸ'  in utf-8 string,cannot get turkish character 'ş',i am getting meaningless characters.

Comment: @sahin Are you sure it's 197 376? As I said this is not possible 376 is not an ascii nor a latin-5 codepage character since those cover only 1 byte in size - 376 is larger than the highest possible byte. Please consider posting your code to read the string.